# Unclear compilation info seqDerivedOrdering is not a valid implicit value for scala.math.Ordering[W]

Tags: scala

What is this info trying to tell me during code compilation in SBT 1.1.6 / Scala 2.12.6? Will it cause problem further down the road later?

`[info]seqDerivedOrdering is not a valid implicit value for scala.math.Ordering[W] because:
[info] hasMatchingSymbol reported error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[info]  found   : [CC[X] <: Seq[X], T]scala.math.Ordering[CC[T]]
[info]  required: scala.math.Ordering[W]`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have

```
scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"
```

in `build.sbt`.

With this compiler option switched on compiler prints some information for debugging implicits. In lines you provided it's just written that `seqDerivedOrdering` doesn't suit as an implicit for `Ordering[W]`. But if you have no other compile errors then probably some other present implicit does.

So basically it's ok.